# Dos Batch Script to copy contents of one folder into another using wildcards

Tags: batch-file, dos, xcopy

I am trying to create a batch script that copies the contents of one folder into another.  Ihave tried this:

```
mkdir "c:\Jamie"
cd c:\jamie_DateTimeStamp*
xcopy * "c:\Jamie"
for /D %%f in (c\jamie_*) do rmdir %%f /s /Q
```

I can get the delete to work but I cannot get the xcopy to work.
things to know
The Jamie_datetimestap folder can be any date and time so I don't have a constant and I need to use a wildcard.
The goal of the script to copy the contents of a folder that has a datetime stamp into a folder that does not have one, then delete the folder with the datetime stamp  I cannot simply rename the folder.

Comment: can you get it to work without using the '*' and giving it specific targets?

Comment: You should try this:
set curr_date=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%
mkdir "c:\Jamie" cd "c:\jamie" mkdir "%curr_date%_backup"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy subfolders with `xcopy` you need option `/s` for subdirectories.
You can not use wildcard in `cd` command though, but you can do a `dir /b Jamie*` and use this inside the for loop as you do for delete to use as target for `cd`.